# To match for a certain number

Tags: perl

I have a file which has a lot of floating point numbers like this:

4.5268e-06 4.5268e-08 4.5678e-01 4.5689e-04...

I need to check if there is atleast one number with an expoenent -1. So, I wrote this short snippet with the regex. The regex works because I checked and it does. But what I am getting in the output is all 1s. I know I am missing something very basic. Please help.

```
#!usr/local/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $i;
my @values;

open(WPR,"test.txt")||die "couldnt open $!";
while(<WPR>)
{
chomp();
push @values,(/\d\.\d\d\d\de+[+-][0][1]/);
}
foreach $i (@values){
print "$i\n";}
close(WPR);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I move the parenthesis, it works fine:

```
push @values,/(\d\.\d\d\d\de+[+-][0][1])/;
```

If there's going to be more than one match on the line, I'd add a `g` at the end.

If you have capture groups, and a list context, then match returns a list of capture results.

If you want to take this to its insane conclusion then:

```
my @values = map { /(\d\.\d\d\d\de+[+-][0][1])/g } <WPR> ;
```

Yes, you can use `<WPR>` in a list context too.

BTW, while your regex works, it probably isn't exactly what you meant.  For example `e+` matches one or more `e`s.  A little simpler might be:

```
/\d\.\d{4}e[+-]01/ ;
```

Which is still going to have other issues like matching `x.xxxxe+01` as well.

Comment: Hi, this works perfectly. But why is it that parenthesis changed? Aren't they grouped anyway?

Comment: The `()` inside the regex is a capture group. It puts stuff in `$1` and returns it in list context (which `push` is). You had the parens around the whole match, making it's return value a list. That doesn't do anything at all.

Answer (score 4):

The regular expression [match operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators) `m` (which you have omitted) returns *true* if it matches. *True* in Perl is usually returned as `1`. (Note that most stuff is *true*, though).

If you want to stick with the short syntax, do this:

```
push @values, $1 if /(\d\.\d\d\d\de+[+-][0][1])/;
```

Comment: Or if OP just wants the matching part: `push @values, $1 if /(\d\.\d\d\d\de+[+-][0][1])/`

Comment: Yeah. Let's play guess: I think they are all in each line. OP is chomping them. This question is full of guesses. :-/

Comment: Question lists numbers as many per line. In which cases simply `push @values, /\d\.\d\d\d\de+[+-][0][1]/g`

Comment: Hi Thanks. I get it but I dont wnat the whole line. I just want that number in the line. If I say $_, it prints the entire line it is readin now, right?

Comment: @Hitch - Yes, `$_` is the entire line. You should find alternatives here in the comments.

Comment: You were right after all @grebneke. ;-) I edited it in. Thanks.

Comment: @simbabque - yeah, but now for the next guess: are there several numbers in each line? ...

Comment: I think there are several in each line, and lot's of lines. That's why `chomp` and why only the one that matches. At $work when I'm asked that stuff I refer to Glaskugel.pm. Go figure.

Comment: Fixes main problem and explains why it's 1s so +1. @Hitch you might consider using a different regex also as the one that you have can be written easier... you can replace `\d\d\d` with just `\d{3}` which means the same, or `\d+` which means 1 or more digits. `e+` can be replaced with just `e` unless you want `eeeeeeeee` to be matched there, `[+-]` => `+` is special character in regexes... so you should rather escape it `[\+-]` (although I am not entirely sure if you actually would like to have `+` matched there)

Comment: @mgsk: in this case there is no need to escape the `+` because it's inside a character group. There can be no quantifiers there. Only the `-` (and some others, but they don't apply here) can be a special char as it's the *from...to* operator. But if it's the last one, no need to escape it either.

Comment: I am sorry but if I try using $1, it gives me an error.And yes, there are many such numbers and many lines and I have so many files to filter through. Thakn you.
And this was the error:
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at config.pl line 18, <WPR> line 7035

Comment: Are you sure you put the `if` part of `push @foo, $1 if m/(bar)/`? There should not be a problem as the `push` does not get called unless there is a match. Strange.

Comment: Good point @simbabque! I would escape it just for "safety & clarity" though so that anyone else doesn't have to wonder about what you pointed out, don't think it would change anything, would it?

Comment: No, it does not change anything. It's just helping human error with the maintenance guy. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try with this one:

```
/\d+\.\d+e-01/
```

Comment: That regex is a lot simpler, but it will still only give the OP a list full of `1`s. ;)